# Inserting a byte array into SQL Server database table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm using the PBKDF2 hashing algorithm for passwords which produces a byte array from my user supplied password, like so:

```
var DeriveBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(_Password, 20);
byte[] _Salt = DeriveBytes.Salt;
byte[] _Key = DeriveBytes.GetBytes(20);  // derive a 20-byte key
```

I want to save these into my database, but I'm not sure what data type to use. From what I can see there's no data type used for byte arrays and I'm pretty sure I can't just convert it to a string and store it with `varchar`, or can I?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`binary` and `varbinary` are pretty much explicitly designed to store byte arrays.

[MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188362.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, although I get an exception raised when I call `ExecuteNonQuery()` on my statement that says `Failed to convert parameter value from a Byte[] to a String.`. I've made sure that the parameter that I'm adding is of `SqlDbType.VarBinary` type.

Comment: @James: That is weird. Please ask another question with the code that you use to initialize the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You define the column in your SQL table as `binary` or `varbinary`, then add it to the parameter property of your ado command object using one of the overloads that require a `SqlDbType` parameter to communicate this is a binary value.

option 2:

You define the column in your SQL table as `nvarchar(max)`, convert your byte array to a base 64 string, i.e. `System.Convert.ToBase64String(mybytes)`. When it's time to retrieve it from the database,

```
mybytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String((byte[])dr[i]);
```